# Padding missing between thumbnails and other app/script information

Tags: bug, status-review, meta, design

On the [Apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [Scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) tabs, the thumbnails and the rest of the information touch each other:

[image]

This [didn't use to be the case](https://web.archive.org/web/20170301031410/http://stackapps.com/), could you please re-add some padding?

Comment: +1 - this is really a less than 5 minute job. Not sure why it's been pending for more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal CSS that could make this a tiny bit better is:

```html
.summary.d-flex .flex--item:first-child { 
  padding-right:8px;
}
```

Compare:

| no 8px padding | with 8px padding |
| --- | --- |
| [image: no padding, image smacked against the text] | [image: with padding, image is just free of the text] |