# Are these images really necessary?

Tags: feature-request, meta, stackapps

In the homepage (mobile phone) there's a huge image on the left side of each question:

[image: images]

But are they really necessary? Should we remove them? The images seem unrelated to the questions themselves. Also, they make the site ugly to my eyes.

Comment: The "images" are the thumbnails offered by the author of the app/script. It is up to them whether they relate to the post. I agree the layout / styling of that page needs some love.

Comment: see also: https://stackapps.com/questions/9420/padding-missing-between-thumbnails-and-other-app-script-information